# Mysql IF statement that checks multiple values that could be null

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a tough time with an SQL statement. I have a KPI (key performance indicator) that might also have an upper bound and lower bound. The person setting up the KPI could elect to set up both, either, or neither bound. I want to display a message on a dashboard that says at a glance whether the value is in bounds or not. For our purposes, a null value can be considered in bounds, and we don't have to be specific about which bound is broken.

So basically I'm trying to construct a statement like:

`Check if the kpi_lower_bound is null or not
If it is not null, check that the kpi_value > kpi_lower_bound
Check if the kpi_upper_bound is null or not
If it is not null, check that the kpi_value < kpi_lower_bound`

`If both statements pass or both are null, return "within bounds".
If either statement fails, return "out of bounds."`

I can check either side of the bounds with a statement like

```
SELECT
IF(kpi_lower_bound IS NOT NULL, (IF(kpi_value < kpi_lower_bound,"Out of lower bounds","Within lower bounds")), "It's null") AS "lower bound break",
```

But I can't figure out how to combine multiple if statements like this into one big conditional check.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trick we can try using is to use `COALESCE` and replace the missing bounds with the following logic:

1. missing lower bound defaults to `2147483647`
2. missing upper bound defaults to `-2147483648`

Then use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN kpi_value < COALESCE(kpi_lower_bound, -2147483648) OR
              kpi_value > COALESCE(kpi_upper_bound, 2147483647)
         THEN 'out of bounds'
         ELSE 'within bounds' END AS bounds
FROM yourTable;
```

The trick here is that when, e.g., the `kpi_lower_bound` is `NULL`, is gets replaced with `-2147483648`, i.e. a very small number, below which we don't expect the `kpi_value` would ever reach.  This has the effect of giving a free pass to any `kpi_value` which might be `NULL`, for the lower bound check.  The same logic applies in reverse for `NULL` values and the upper bound check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with CASE WHEN

```
SELECT
cast when kpi_lower_bound IS NOT NULL 
   then case when kpi_value < kpi_lower_bound then 'Out of lower bounds' else 'Within lower bounds' end
else 'It''s null' end AS "lower bound break"
```